# Get parent directive in child

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have app_form and app_input components (directives) for angular2. I can use them in template  in different ways:

```
template: `
  <app_form>
    <app_inp></app_inp>
  </app_form>
`
```

and independently:

```
template: '<app_inp></app_inp>'
```

In the first case, the directive app_inp is added by calling a function from parent, and in the second everything works as usual in angular2. Anybody know how to do it? Thank you.

UPD:

```
export class InputComponent {  
  constructor() {}
  ngAfterViewInit() { // maybe ngAfterViewInit isn't the best way
    if(!isHasParentForm){    // if we have parent directive app_form  
      // we run some logic for adding our component
    } else {
      // if we don't have parent like app_form we run different logic
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add more information about what you try to accomplish. Can you please try to explain a bit more what this means "In the first case, the directive app_inp is added by calling a function from parent, and in the second everything works as usual in angular2."

Comment: Adding some more code that shows what you try to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: I added some code. I hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the type of the parent is known statically, you can just inject it

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form-cmp',
  providers: [],
  template: `
  <div>form</div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class FormComponent {}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-inp',
  providers: [],
  template: `
  <div>myInp</div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class MyInput {
    constructor(private form:FormComponent) {
      console.log(form);
    }
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
  <form-cmp>
    <my-inp></my-inp>
  </form-cmp>
  `,
  directives: [FormComponent, MyInput]
})
export class App {}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/TTgWoT24PNpr60tVuxkH?p=preview)

Comment: but we can't use my-inp independently  [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/bvnLiJzcHvlI5X3L1Uvd?p=preview)

Comment: Sure you can :) Just prepend `@Optional()` https://plnkr.co/edit/elerguYGQjtFa7LBoOYx?p=preview

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Optional-decorator.html